# Converting a static HTML design to blog-like style reminiscent of magazine and finding a working CSS style?

Tags: html, css

This is the codepen for my HTML layout for a magazine - [link here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROremm).

I have been experimenting with the CSS and trying to achieve a more blog-like design with my CSS, to emulate the effect seen at  https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/bmw/7-series/first-drives/bmw-7-series-750li-xdrive-2019-review

(well, the way the article and sidebar with other articles is; the article and Driven this week part)

Currently I have this CSS:

```
body {
background-color: gray;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

p {
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 21px;
}

header {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.article {
width: 800px;
height: auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
overflow: auto;
padding: 5px;
}

div.article img {
height: 340px;
}
```

but what sort of padding etc. could I use while keeping the div.article as white (FFFFFF) and get the header to work more effectively with the title?

if the header is in anything but h1, h2, h3 etc. it doesn't quite work - example at forked codepen.io copy - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBgQjw

Although this uses Verdana here for ease of use, what's the best way of getting FontSquirrel fonts like OpenSans to work locally (i.e. not linking to online source, but the directory the fonts are in); I've often used .ttf when doing fonts other than Arial or Verdana.

I may be using Gotham font soon, but for now it's OpenSans and OpenSans Bold.

OpenSans Bold is for h1, h2 in the CSS soon.

This is only a testing page on localhost, but it maybe used as a template for a PHP site.

No Javascript is in use yet but if you have any good suggestions for ones that could work, I'd appreciate it. (I've kept the design simple for now).

The grey background will be kept, and div.article in white.

I would welcome any advice on how to turn this from looking rather staid into a more professional, blog-like design.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a SINGLE specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try to use a CSS framework, e.g. Bulma (which is lightweight and easy to use and based on CSS flexbox). See Bulma docs here: https://bulma.io/documentation/

As for the font implementation I think @font-face should do the trick - you just have to download the font to your server (or local device).